# jQuery on() - Doesn't work on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to call .on from within javascript function but doesn't work on the first click but does with second, what am I doing wrong? I know this works fine with $(document).ready(function(){}); but need to call from the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    function callMe() {
        $("a").on("click", function(){
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><TD><a href="#" onclick="javascript:callMe();">[Delete]</a> </TD></tr><
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

### jQuery:

This where I actually using .on() to remove table row when user click. So I would have to call .on() from the js function, as you can see I am passing the url from the page like:

```
<TD> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="disabledConfirm_exit=true;javascript:(new removeFileAJAX()).removeFile('dynamic action url coming from the server');">[Remove]</a></TD> 


function removeFileAJAX(){ 
var sendForm = $("#replyMessageForm");  
    return {
        removeFile: function(url) {             
            $("a").on("click", function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });                             
            var that = this;                
            var options = { 
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<portlet:actionURL><portlet:param name="action" value="upload"/></portlet:actionURL>',
                data: $(this).serialize(),                  
                cache: false,                   
                success: function(response){                                                                                                            
                    that.removeFileList();                      
                }
            };                              
            var ajaxForm = sendForm.ajaxForm(options);
            ajaxForm.submit();
            alert('action submit'); 
        },
        removeFileList: function() {                        
        var that = this;
                var options = { 
                    type: 'POST',                       
                    url: '<portlet:resourceURL id="renderRemFile"> </portlet:resourceURL>',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){ 
                        ..do stuff;                                                                         
                    }
                };
                var ajaxForm =  sendForm.ajaxForm(options);     
                ajaxForm.submit();
                alert('resource submit');                               
        }       
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally fine to declare what javascript functions should be executed inside the HTML. But what you actually want to do is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    function callMe(element) {
        $(element).parent().parent().remove();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><TD><a href="#" onclick="callMe(this);">[Delete]</a> </TD></tr><
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `onclick` ***adds*** the `click` event listener, it doesn't actually fire the event listener function.

What you really want to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
        $("a").on("click", function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">[Delete]</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, if you like the `onclick` method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
        function clickMe {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="clickMe">[Delete]</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**A couple other notes:**

1. Using `href="#"` is not properly supported in all browsers. Some browsers will reload the page when the link is clicked. You should instead use `href="javascript:void(0)"`.
2. Your selector (`"a"`) selects all `a`s on the page. Instead, you probably want to assign a `class` or `id` to your `a` and then use that to select the specific `a`.

Comment: The OP didn't specify, but it's worth noting that the first example will remove the parent's parent of every link that is clicked on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
 onclick="javascript:callMe();"
```

And don't assing the event inside a function just let:

```
  $("a").on("click", function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

Basically your are assigning the event after the you call callMe() that's why removes the element until the 2nd click

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I do need to perform the removal from within js function, because in that function there are other operations e.g. ajax call to server to remove the record from model, that need to be carried out before removing the row.

Comment: You sill dont need the function, you can do: $("a").on("click", function(){ $.ajax({ 
   url:'',
   success:     function(result) {   $(this).parent().parent().remove();}
 });

    });

Answer (score 1):

Your function callMe sets an on click listener rather than just performing the method.  You are also defining the onclick listener in the html:

```
    function callMe() {
        // This sets a listener, so on the first click it begins 
        // for any click on an 'a' element.
        $("a").on("click", function(){
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    }



<body>
<table>
<!-- This calls the method above, and will set an on-click listener each
   time it is clicked.  After the 2nd click, you'll have two events associated with 'a' clicks that both get fired, and so on -->
<tr><TD><a href="#" onclick="javascript:callMe();">[Delete]</a> </TD></tr><
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you wanted to keep the html the same, you could change your javascript to only do the business:

```
function callMe() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

I would avoid setting listeners on all `a` elements on the page, because you probably don't want to remove the parent's parent for every single link on the page.

Comment: Technically, every time you click on the `[Delete]` button, you are creating a new event listener. This could be very bad if you are doing things like sending an AJAX request because it will fire the request multiple times.

Comment: I should have been more clear, that was exactly what I was trying to point out with the way the OP had it, which is why I have it commented.